# Settings state's interface to contain a enum value throws error

Tags: typescript

Trying to run the following:

```js
type Mode = 'signup' | 'signin' | 'forgot-password';

interface IProps {}

interface IState {
  mode: Mode;
}

class SigninSignupModal extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  state = {
    mode: 'signup',
  };
}
```

Throws the following error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Mode'. ts(2416)
```

Why is that?

For instance, this is perfectly fine:

```js
type Mode = 'signup' | 'signin' | 'forgot-password';

let mode: Mode = 'signup';
```

And also, this is fine:

```js
class SigninSignupModal extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  construct() {
    this.state = {
      mode: 'signup',
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to explicitly cast your `string` to `Mode` type:

```
this.state = {
  mode: 'signup' as Mode,
};
```

or

```
    this.state = {
      mode: <Mode>'signup',
    };
```

For more info, scroll to "Type assertions":
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html